# Declare an array variable to the controller/component [Laravel, October CMS]

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, laravel, octobercms

I am using October CMS and have no idea how to add an array to the component which serves a similar purpose of the Laravel's controller. Basically it is for my site search functionality. The thing is, it always throws an **Array to String conversion ERROR**. If you look at the code, the problem lies at the last line `$this->$results = $results;` because `$results` is a multidimensional array.

```
/**
 * Component setup.
 *
 * @return void
 */
  public function onRun()
  {
      $this->search();
  }

  /**
  * Initiate the search
  *
  *@return void
  */
   public function search()
   {
     // Sets the parameters from the get request to the variables.
      $popularno = Request::get('q');

      // Perform the query using Query Builder
      $estates = DB::table('makler_realestate_objects')
          ->where('slug', 'like', "%${popularno}%")
          ->get();

      // Now build a results array
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($estates as $estate) {
         $i++;

         $results[$i] = [
             'title'     => $estate->prim_id,
             'text'      => $estate->sifra_id,
             'url'       => 'nepremicnina/' . $estate->slug,
         ];
       }

       print_r($results);
       $this->$results = $results; // This is the issue
  }
```

I want to declare it to the component so I can call it on the page with `{% set results = Search.results %}` and loop through each array item with a for loop.

```
{% for result in results %}
 <li>{{result.title}} {{result.text}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign an array as a property name by using an extra `$`. Take it out and you should be fine.

```
$this->results = $results;
```

Comment: I have spent waaay to much time trying to solve this. Thank you very much for your help. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.